# Can I do a Where Clause on this LINQ Query?

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
Dim dataContext As New ACSLostFoundEntities()

Dim query = From s In dataContext.FosterForms() _
            Join c In dataContext.Fosters() _
            On c.License Equals s.License _
            Where s.Deleted = "False" _
            Select New With {.License = s.License, _
                             .LastName = s.LastName, _
                             .FirstName = s.FirstName, _
                             .Status = s.Status, _
                             .WantedPets = dataContext.WantedPets(c)}
```

At the end of this I want to do a Where `WantedPets.Contains(criteria)`, is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have

```
Where s.Deleted = "False" _
AndAlso dataContext.WantedPets(c).Contains(criteria) _
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It was I who was missing something obvious!  Thanks!